# Intuition for lines which undergo linear transformations

Tags: linear-transformations

From what I understand, a 2D line $y = \frac{1}{2} x$ can be specified with a vector $v = [\frac{1}{2}, -1]^T$ such that the line can be written as $v^T \bar{x} = 0$ (where $\bar{x} = [x,y]^T$).

Now, consider a linear transformation given by the matrix $M$ (say a rotation). Denoting the line that has been transformed with this particular linear transformation as $v'$, I understand that we can write:
$$
v' = vM^{-1}
$$
Is there any intuitive explanation as to why this happens to be the case? From my (misguided) perspective, I would have thought that we might have something like $v' = Mv$ instead, which is wrong, but I don't exactly have a good intuition as to why this is wrong.

I'm hoping to get a better understanding of this, as I'd like to be able to apply these arguments to the linear transformation of more complicated geometric structures, such as conics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transformation formula isn’t quite right. It’s actually $v'=M^{-T}v$—you apply the inverse transpose of $M$.

Algebraically, this can be derived using a simple substitution. If you have the point transformation $\bar x' = M\bar x$, then $$v^T\bar x = v^T(M^{-1}\bar x') = (v^TM^{-1})\bar x' = (M^{-T}v)^T\bar x'=0.$$ This is really no different than the process that you might’ve gone through when translating and scaling graphs of functions in your pre-calculus algebra courses: In order to, say, stretch the graph of $f(x)$ by a factor of $3$, you have to replace $x$ by $x/3$—that is, you have to invert the transformation in order to substitute for the original $x$ in the function’s expression. It’s the same here: to get the equation of the line in terms of the new coordinates $\bar x'$, you have to solve for the components of $\bar x$ in terms of those of $\bar x'$—invert $M$—in order to substitute for the former in the equation of the line.

Even though they might look similar, a coordinate vector that represents a point and one that represents a line are different—they transform differently under $M$. The terms that you may encounter for these two types of vectors are *contravariant* and *covariant*, respectively. In three dimensions, you might also see the terms *polar* vector and *pseudovector* (or *axial* vector). This different behavior under transformations is also connected to the concept of the *dual* $V^*$ of a vector space $V$, which is the space of linear functionals on $V$, but I won’t go into that here.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my error, I understand it now (:

Comment: @SeanLee I was planning to add a bit of discussion of what’s going on geometrically, but since you’ve accepted the answer, I’ll leave it alone.

Comment: Ah, I meant I understand the algebraic derivation, but I'd really appreciate it if you could expand on the explanation with the dual space!